# How to unlock bootloader on Android on a User Build

Tags: android, bootloader, fastboot, android-rom

I have tried everything to unlock the boot loader on my Android 410 device.  I have an AOSP based ROM on it (not a production device).

I turned on USB debugging, turned on 'OEM unlock' and tried the following in fastboot mode:

Images-Debug$ sudo fastboot flashing unlock
...
FAILED (remote: unknown command)
finished. total time: 0.001s

Images-Debug$ sudo fastboot oem unlock
...
FAILED (remote: unknown command)
finished. total time: 0.001s

Images-Debug$ sudo fastboot flashing unlock_critical
...
FAILED (remote: unknown command)
finished. total time: 0.001s

But, seems I cannot get FastBoot to do anything.